# Java thread run method

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

In my pregame I have a thread and it's run method must have Queue as input:

```
@Override
public void run(Queue q) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    A = q.pop();
    System.out.println(A * A + "Pop1");

}
```

And in this case the run method is not an implemented method of my runnable class, so how can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the queue as an argument in your constructor. Or add it in a setter.
Remove the argument from the run method, but keep it in the method body.

Answer (score 0):

You write a second `run` method with the right signature for `Runnable`. This one can then get the queue somehow and call the other `run` method.

Answer (score 0):

from the original run() method of the thread , call run(Queue q) method

```
@Override
public void run() {

 //call the run(Queue q) method from here
}

public void run(Queue q) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
A = q.pop();
System.out.println(A * A + "Pop1");
```

}

Comment: Several flaws: a) The ``@Override`` is at the wrong method; b) This does not clarify where from he should take the ``Queue`` reference; c) this type of "delegation" is really not appropriate here.

Comment: @f1sh.. I mistakenly put the override .. i've corrected it .. b)Do you really think a normal Java programmer wouldn't know how to call a parameterized method ? Don't put silly comments like these please . c) Please tell me why this is not appropriate ...

Comment: Add a setter or constructor arg to set the queue and your answer will be complete. Having an extra method that does nothing more than call another method is in this case not appropriate.